# Documentation for maven dependencies?

Tags: intellij-idea

For core Java imports Intellij gives a description on-hover of the method and what it does, however for maven dependcies such as Spring-Context this does not happen.

I tried in VSCode and I get the on-hover descriptions there too (Eclipse as well). How can I set this up to work in Intellij?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Download Sources** / **Documentation** in the **Maven** tool window:

[image: download sources]